# Form still closing when I choose no

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (cmd.cetakTanya("Are you sure you want to exit ?"))
    {
        cmd.cetakSukses("Thank you for using " + cmd.title);
        startURL();
    }
}

public bool cetakTanya(string message)
{
    bool status = false;

    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        status = true;
    }
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        status = false;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Why does my form still closed even though I choose "NO" at the confirmation dialog?

Comment: To actually keep it from closing, you need to use the FormClosingEventArgs. You can pass in the FormClosingEventArgs to your cetakTanya method and on dialogResult.No, you can set e.Cancel = true to keep the form from closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Cancel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to cancel the event if "no" is clicked.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (cmd.cetakTanya("Are you sure you want to exit ?"))
    {
        cmd.cetakSukses("Thank you for using " + cmd.title);
        startURL();
    }
    else
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Additionally, your method could be refactored to be a bit more compact:

```
public bool cetakTanya(string message)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    return result == DialogResult.Yes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i am using `cetakTanya()` confirmation dialog to ensure that DML is going to executed ! apparently, i am using the same method to make a confirmation on closing form which is doesn't work. i have to use `cancel` to make it work. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You need to cancel the event:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (cmd.cetakTanya("Are you sure you want to exit ?"))
    {
        cmd.cetakSukses("Thank you for using " + cmd.title);
        startURL();
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```